# Manipulating socketstream in Python

Tags: python, sockets, openldap

I'm trying to create a small, multithreaded proxyscript that allows me to proxy LDAP requests and manipulate the results (like adding extra fields, renaming them etc).

In the example below, I try to replace the field 'TEST' by 'DONE'. Is there any solution to allow this socketstream to be manipulated? Should I decode it somewhat first?

```
import select
import socket
import sys
import threading
import signal
import re
import random
import time
import binascii

from ldaptor.protocols import pureldap, pureber
from time import gmtime, strftime

ASTLDAP_PROXY_PORT = 1389
ASTLDAP_HOST = 'localhost'
ASTLDAP_PORT = 389
BUFFERSIZE = 1024
DELAY = 0.0001

class Forward:
    def __init__(self):
        self.forward = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.forward.connect((host, port))
            return self.forward
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            return False

class AstLdapProxyServer(threading.Thread):
    input_list = []
    channel = {}

    def __init__(self, host, port, socket):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    # Socket ontvangen die we meekregen bij nieuwe thread.
    self.socket = socket
    print "[+] New thread started for "+host+":"+str(port)
    self.socket.bind((host, port))
    self.socket.listen(200)

def register_signals(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, self.signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, self.signal_handler)

def main_loop(self):
    self.input_list.append(self.socket)
    while 1:
        #time.sleep(DELAY)
        ss = select.select
        inputready, outputready, exceptready = ss(self.input_list, [], [])
        for self.s in inputready:
            if self.s == self.socket:
                self.on_accept()
                break

            self.data = self.s.recv(BUFFERSIZE)
            if len(self.data) == 0:
                self.on_close()
            else:
                self.on_recv()

def on_accept(self):
    forward = Forward().start(ASTLDAP_HOST, ASTLDAP_PORT)
    clientsock, clientaddr = self.socket.accept()
    if forward:
        print clientaddr, "has connected"
        self.input_list.append(clientsock)
        self.input_list.append(forward)
        self.channel[clientsock] = forward
        self.channel[forward] = clientsock
    else:
        print "Can't establish connection with remote server.",
        print "Closing connection with client side", clientaddr
        clientsock.close()

def on_close(self):
    print self.s.getpeername(), "has disconnected"
    #remove objects from input_list
    self.input_list.remove(self.s)
    self.input_list.remove(self.channel[self.s])
    out = self.channel[self.s]
    # close the connection with client
    self.channel[out].close()  # equivalent to do self.s.close()
    # close the connection with remote server
    self.channel[self.s].close()
    # delete both objects from channel dict
    del self.channel[out]
    del self.channel[self.s]


def on_recv(self):
    data = self.data
    # Manipulate result
    output = re.sub(r'uzgEmail1', r'TEST', data)

    # Send result to client (DOESN'T WORK)
    self.channel[self.s].send(output)

    # Send result to client (WORKS when I disable send above)
    self.channel[self.s].send(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    server = AstLdapProxyServer(ASTLDAP_HOST, ASTLDAP_PROXY_PORT, tcpsock)
    server.start()
    try:
        server.main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: You need to explain what "DOESN'T WORK" mean here.

Comment: The values in the socketstream seem to have successfully changed from uzgEmail1 to TEST, but the client doesn't receive a valid LDAP response afterwards.